# C - Store the results of strtok?

Tags: c, split, token, delimiter, strtok

So I'm trying getting my input as `file.txt,r` and I have to split the string on the comma and save both `file.txt` and `r` into separate strings... but I'm really confused how to do that. I looked up [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)
and this is what I have so far:

```
 char buffer[256];
 char filename[2][40];
 char operation[20]; 
n = read(sock,buffer,255);    //read the message from the client into buffer
char cinput[300];
strcpy(cinput,buffer);//now cinput has the whole thing

   char *token;

   token = strtok(cinput,",");

   while(token)
   {
       printf("%s\n",token);
       token = strtok(NULL,",");
   }
```

But I'm confused... how would I store `file.txt` and `r` as separate strings once parsed?

edit: something like this?

```
       char *token;

   char *pt;

   pt = strtok(cinput,","); //this will hold the value of the first one
   strcpy(filename,pt);


   token = strtok(cinput,",");
   while(token)
   {
       //printf("%s\n",token);
       token = strtok(NULL,",");
   }
   printf("%s\n",token); //this will hold the value of the second one

   strcpy(operation,token);

   printf("%s\n",operation);
```

Comment: Thanks.. so I changed edited my question a little bit. However, when i'm using `strcpy()` how would I store the first vs. second token? Because if I just did it the way above, wouldn't I be storing `r` in `filename`?

Comment: Use a 2-d array (filename) , and store strings in it .

Comment: use a higher level language or implement a linked list, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you should need is separate pointers. You don't need to allocate all these buffers or use `strcpy()`.

Just assign the return values from `strtok()` in multiple `char *` pointers.

Something like:

```
char *p1 = strtok("file.txt,r", ",");
char *p2 = strtok(NULL, ",");
```

Comment: Thanks!! So I think I implemented something very similar to that.

Comment: Okay, I guess my question is also that I have the right values, but I don't understand how I would get the token values into strings... for some reason `strcpy(filename,pt)` doesn't work

Comment: That works just fine if `pt` is a pointer to a parsed token. Given my code snippet above, you could do `strcpy(buff, p1)` or `strcpy(buff, p2)`.

Answer (score 2):

may be a compact approach

```
//your data pattern 
    typedef
    struct file_inputs {
        char *fname;
        char *fmode;
    } finput_t;
```

and some where in your code

```
finput_t fi;

fi.fname = strtok(cinput,",");
fi.fmode = strtok(NULL,",");
```